# oops! OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, memory-leaks

guys.
my problem is OutOfMemoryError Exception. but anyhow i controlled it a lot using system.gc()
and clearing my stuff as soon as its not required, but system.gc is not working for android 1.5 and 1.6 framework. and hence i am not able to control OutOfMemoryError on 1.5 and 1.6.
for rest of releases application works fine. is this a problem of lower version releases or something else????? I tested it a lot , it works fine from android 2.0 onwards

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, System.gc() won't save you from OutOfMemoryError. It's not caused by excessive garbage (objects with no references), but it may be caused by too much referenced objects in the heap.
So, try to look for memory leaks in your program. Example: you add elements to a list or hash map, but never remove them. They remain referenced in the heap, and GC cannot collect them.

Comment: - whats your idea about the code at this link http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/943/how-to-increase-download-speed-using-following-method-please-review.                 I released all objects but it still shows OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: @Shashank_Itmaster: wrote you an answer there